# onMove with Multiarray in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

i need a little extra help with the onMove modifier and a multi array.
Is there a way to use the onMove modifier with a multiarray?
Thanks in advance!

```
@State var multiArray = [["String_1"],["String_2"]]
@State var edit: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        
        List {
            
            Section{
                Button {
                    edit.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Edit")
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            }
            
            ForEach(0..<multiArray.count, id:\.self ){ i in
                ForEach(multiArray[i], id:\.self ){ string in
                    Text(string)
                }
            }.onMove(perform: move2)
            
        }.environment(\.editMode, .constant(edit ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive))
    }
}
func move2(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    
    multiArray.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    
}
```

Comment: I've tried before, but it didn't work... would be interested in a solution too

Comment: This is still not possible directly in SwiftUI.  You can fallback to UIKit - See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492720/drag-item-from-one-list-to-another-list-in-swiftui

Comment: you can try `onDrag`, `onDrop` or `onInsert` similar functionality but doesn't require the `editMode`